# Interfacing two PIC microcontrollers, of different power sources?

Tags: pic, voltage

I have two different circuits with 5v for each, and they are using PIC microcontroller, how can I send a data (voltage) from the first PIC using output pin to the other PIC using its input pin? I measured the output from the first PIC, it is 5v (great), but measuring it using the ground of the other circuit it is ZERO, why??????

Note: NO COMMON GROUND, THEY ARE ISOLATED CIRCUITS.

Comment: Your last sentence answers your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to send directly data using an electrical connection you need to have a common reference voltage, that reference level is normally the ground but if the circuits are isolated from each-other you can use an [optocoupler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opto-isolator)

[image]

Here is some related reading http://www.circuitstoday.com/optocoupler-devices-and-application

Comment: Thanks, but can we use a Transistor as a switch, I don't need the actual voltage value from the first circuit, I just need to know if there is a voltage (+V) or zero (0V)?

Comment: @user3143588: Did you read the last sentence in the question?

Comment: So, this is the ONLY solution?

Comment: @logicchild: Of course not. You could use a speaker an a microphone. You could use an inductor and a hall sensor. You could use a motor and a generator. But if you want an integrated solution, you'll use an optoisolator.

Answer (score 2):

To feed signals between two points with arbitrarily-different ground potentials, one basically needs to use either a transformer or an optocoupler.  Optocouplers are often smaller and cheaper than transformers, and can communicate DC as well as AC levels, but transformers are capable of transferring useful amounts of energy, and can in many cases carry data faster than optocouplers can.

If the ground potentials differ significantly, but in a known way, it may be possible to transfer data using either resistively- or capacitively-coupled differential signalling, or using current-based signalling.  These approaches can be particularly good if, for example, if one subcircuit's ground is tied to a big battery's negative rail, while the other subcircuit's ground is 3 volts below the battery's positive rail.  Capacitive differential signalling may also be usable in cases where the only thing known about the grounds is that the potential difference between them isn't likely to change particularly fast particularly often (when using differential capacitive coupling, sudden changes in ground potential may disrupt communication; the recipient will be able to tell that this has happened).